# Joda-time Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in applet

Tags: java, jodatime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My code compiles in Eclipse but I get a ClassNotFound at runtime how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764614/my-code-compiles-in-eclipse-but-i-get-a-classnotfound-at-runtime-how-can-i-fix-i)

I'm referencing Joda Time in an applet and when I debug inside Eclipse everything runs as expected. However when I export my jar file I get an error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/joda/time/ReadableInstant

at runtime.

What am I missing?

Comment: Many thanks, my question was a duplicate. In the end I used FatJar from a suggestion in one of the replies to the duplicate question. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Put the joda jar in the `<web-server-root>/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib` directory