# Android game development with Cocos2d lib

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I want to develop game development with Cocos2d . I am following the tutorial http://dan.clarke.name/2011/04/how-to-make-a-simple-android-game-with-cocos2d/ . I added external cocos2d-android.jar file but when i run sample apps then caused following error. please anyone help me.

```
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.cocos2d.opengl.CCGLSurfaceView
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.agv.Cocos2d.CoCos2dActivity.onCreate(CoCos2dActivity.java:24)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-18 13:09:50.783: E/AndroidRuntime(497):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError usually means that the library has not being included in the compilation process. Check that you have added all the relevant jar files and that it is in the Build path in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

check your manifest file. you have to declare the activities. I had similar problem and i solved it this way.

Comment: If this was a manifest problem, it would be an ActivityNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Put the jar file into your project lib directory and then change the build path to this path. It solved my problem.
If you will not put the jar files into your project then while building the apk it won't take the directory path which is on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

After you verify all the files are where they should be. Check to see if your hitting code that requires a permission that you might be missing.

[My code compiles in Eclipse but I get a ClassNotFound at runtime how can I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764614/my-code-compiles-in-eclipse-but-i-get-a-classnotfound-at-runtime-how-can-i-fix-i/)